# Centering in a table

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}

 \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{5cm} | p{5cm} | p{7cm} |}\hline

\centering{A} &     
\centering{B} &     
\centering{C} \\ \hline

\end{tabular} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I am making an A4 document and I want the words in the first row of the table to be centered. Here I have omitted other rows. But errors occur and it seems that I can't use \centering for the last column. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "middle vertical align[ment]". Please elaborate.

Comment: @Mico : I mean 'paragraph column with text vertically aligned in the middle' (from wiki) and therefore i use the code m{5cm}.

Comment: @LeeKM It should be `\begin{tabular}{|m{2.8cm}|m{2.8cm}|m{5cm}|} \hline A & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{B} & C \\\hline A & B & I want the first two columns to have middle vertical align but the last column remains to have `top' alignment. \\\hline\end{tabular}`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi : thx for replying. Actually I want to keep the width of the columns as 5cm, 5cm and 7cm. Will this restriction prohibit me using \centering?

Comment: If the table is supposed to be at least 17cm wide, it will likely not fit inside the text block (unless the paper size is unusually large and/or the margins are unusually narrow).

Comment: @Mico : in short, centering does not work since i insist i) using A4 paper and ii) having a 17cm-long-table?

Comment: Well, if you set the margins to something like 5mm, centering will work...

Comment: @Mico : i see! i would appreciate that if you can show a simple example and put it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the width of the `tabular` exceeding 17cm, the margins have to be quite narrow if the material is supposed to fit inside the textblock. In the example below, the margins are set to 1cm. (Aside: rather than setting puny margins, I'd reduce the column widths in the tabular.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % filler text
\begin{document}

\hrule %% just to illustrate width of text block

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{5cm} | p{5cm} | p{7cm} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{C} \\ 
\hline
\lipsum*[2] & \lipsum*[2] & \lipsum*[2] \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```